# Match a string against multiple patterns

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I match a string against multiple patterns using regular expression in ruby.

I am trying to see if a string is included in an array of prefixes, This is not working but I think it demonstrates at least what I am trying to do.

```
# example:
# prefixes.include?("Mrs. Kirsten Hess")

prefixes.include?(name) # should return true / false

prefixes = [
  /Ms\.?/i,
  /Miss/i,
  /Mrs\.?/i,
  /Mr\.?/i,
  /Master/i,
  /Rev\.?/i,
  /Reverend/i,
  /Fr\.?/i,
  /Father/i,
  /Dr\.?/i,
  /Doctor/i,
  /Atty\.?/i,
  /Attorney/i,
  /Prof\.?/i,
  /Professor/i,
  /Hon\.?/i,
  /Honorable/i,
  /Pres\.?/i,
  /President/i,
  /Gov\.?/i,
  /Governor/i,
  /Coach/i,
  /Ofc\.?/i,
  /Officer/i,
  /Msgr\.?/i,
  /Monsignor/i,
  /Sr\.?/i,
  /Sister\.?/i,
  /Br\.?/i,
  /Brother/i,
  /Supt\.?/i,
  /Superintendent/i,
  /Rep\.?/i,
  /Representative/i,
  /Sen\.?/i,
  /Senator/i,
  /Amb\.?/i,
  /Ambassador/i,
  /Treas\.?/i,
  /Treasurer/i,
  /Sec\.?/i,
  /Secretary/i,
  /Pvt\.?/i,
  /Private/i,
  /Cpl\.?/i,
  /Corporal/i,
  /Sgt\.?/i,
  /Sargent/i,
  /Adm\.?/i,
  /Administrative/i,
  /Maj\.?/i,
  /Major/i,
  /Capt\.?/i,
  /Captain/i,
  /Cmdr\.?/i,
  /Commander/i,
  /Lt\.?/i,
  /Lieutenant/i,
  /^Lt Col\.?$/i,
  /^Lieutenant Col$/i,
  /Col\.?/i,
  /Colonel/i,
  /Gen\.?/i,
  /General/i
]
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Use [`Regexp.union`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-union) to combine them:

> **union(pats_ary) → new_regexp**
>
> Return a `Regexp` object that is the union of the given *patterns*, i.e., will match any of its parts.

So this will do:

```
re = Regexp.union(prefixes)
```

then you use `re` as your regex:

```
if name.match(re)
    #...
```

Comment: @Kyle: Thanks. `Regexp.union` can be a lot nicer to use than trying to build a big alternation regex by hand.

Answer (score 14):

If you can use a single string, it might be faster to write a regex containing the possible values.

e.g.

```
/(Mr\.|Mrs\.| ... )/.match(name)
```