# Checking whether a string matches any regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have an array of regular expressions and an array of strings. The size of the arrays can be arbitrarily long (say, 100 or 1000). No string matches two different regexes. I am not sure how I will be enforcing it, but let's just assume that it's there. The regexes begin with `pre`, followed by an optional colon, followed by one or more spaces, followed by a specific string, followed by a single space, followed by an integer. It will be case-insensitive.

```
regexes = [/pre: my_string (\d+)/i, /pre: another (\d+)/i]
strings = ["comet", "eclipse", "sunshine", "starlight", "moonlight"]
```

For each string, I want to check which regex it matches and return the corresponding match. 
The sample code above demonstrates my current approach.

```
strings.each {|string|
  regexes.each {|regex|
    if regex.match(string)
      p regex.match(string)
      break
    end
  }
}
```

It seems inefficient. What is a more efficient way to implement this?

Comment: Do the regexes follow any kind of pattern or are they totally general?

Comment: Yes, there is a specific pattern that I currently have in my design. I have included a description of it.

Comment: Do you care which particular regex matches?

Comment: No. Just return the first match and move on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Match a string against multiple paterns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731649/match-a-string-against-multiple-paterns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an array of regexes; instead, use a search tree.

Here's a great intro article: Fast Algorithms for Sorting and Searching Strings.

- http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/comp150fp/archive/bob-sedgewick/fast-strings.pdf

Or if you prefer a quick-and-dirty solution, you could use Ruby Regexp#union to fuseregexps together to create one big one. This will likely be more efficient at detecting when *none* of the strings match, and you can benchmark it. If it matches, then you use the match position to figure out which of the regexps matched.

- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-union

(Thanks to comment from "mu is too short" for the #union method)

For your particular case that you describe, where all the regexps start with "pre" and an optional colon, etc. then you can do /pre:? +(star|moon|sun)/ and use the match result to find out which matched.

Ruby's Regexp is implemented using a search tree; there's an interesting description that may give you leads here:

- http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/4/3/exploring-rubys-regular-expression-algorithm

Comment: You don't need any monkey patching when you have [`Regexp.union`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-union).

Comment: @mu You're totally right-- great point, and exactly why StackOverflow is so great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'll just include an example of Regexp.union()

```
desired = Regexp.union(/RM/, /dog/, /hat/)
x = "RM20"
y = "phat"
puts "rawr!" if y =~ desired
#=> rawr!
puts "match!" if x =~ desired
#=> match
```